# p4 changes actually restricted to certain depot path

Tags: perforce

I want to list the changes that have committed changes to certain depot paths

```
p4 changes //depot/path/blah/...
```

will not properly restrict changes to those that occurred on the given depot path but will in fact list changes made on a work space with a view path was equal to, or a superset of that path, regardless of whether any of the actual files changed were in the interested path.

e.g. changes made in a workspace containing a view on one of these paths:

```
//depot/path/blah/...
//depot/path/...
//depot/...
```

(possibly also requiring that a file was committed on one of those paths, I haven't tested that additional requirement)

creating a view on //depot/... may be daft, but if someone has done that, then their changes on //depot/OTHER-PATH/... will be fetched by

```
p4 changes //depot/path/blah/...
```

How can I restrict p4 changes to those changes that actually committed a file to the specified path?

I can read the entire output of p4 changes and run:
    p4 files @=${change} | grep '^(...)'
where ... is a regex to match all of the depot paths I passed to p4 changes, to detect if any of the files were actually in the relevant depot path

but it seems very expensive to have to double-check all output, surely perforce can filter or check the output of p4 changes ?

For interest here is the full BASH snippet that works, $@ is a list of depot paths (but without proper input sanity checking on $@):

```
ifs_join() {  echo "$*" ; }

p4 changes -s submitted -i "$@" |
while read _1 change _rest ; do
      p4 files @=$change 2>&- | 
      egrep "^($(IFS='|' ifs_join "${@%%...}"))" >/dev/null && echo "$_1 $change $_rest"
done
```

Comment: The behavior you're describing sounds wrong. What version of the server are you running? Are you obliterating files in your depot? Have you contacted Perforce Technical Support?

Comment: obliteration was a clue. Many many of the p4 files @=123456 return: 
@=123456 - no such file(s).

I can no longer find instances of wrong paths, so maybe such instances were a typo on my part.

Maybe all the wrongly returned changes were obliterated

Comment: If 'obliterate' is causing 'changes' to report incorrect results, that would be unfortunate, and is arguably a bug in 'changes'. It would be worth reporting that to Perforce so that they can get it fixed in the future.